# BERT model loading not working with pytorch 1.3.1-eia container

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I have a custom python file for inference in which I have implemented the functions `model_fn`, `input_fn`, `predict_fn` and `output_fn`.  I have saved the model as a torchscript using `torch.jit.trace`, `torch.jit.save` and loading it using `torch.jit.load`. The `model_fn` implementation is as follows:

```
import torch
import os
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
is_ei = os.getenv("SAGEMAKER_INFERENCE_ACCELERATOR_PRESENT") == "true"
logger.warn(f"Elastic Inference enabled: {is_ei}")

def model_fn(model_dir):
    model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, "model_best.pt")
    try:
        loaded_model = torch.jit.load(model_path, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
        loaded_model.eval()
        return loaded_model
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(f"Exception in model fn {e}")
        return None
```

This implementation works perfectly for the container with pytorch 1.5. But for container with torch 1.3.1 it exits abruptly when loading the pretrained model without any logs. The only line I see in the logs is

```
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,392 [WARN ] W-9000-model com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.BatchAggregator - Load model failed: model, error: Worker died.
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,393 [INFO ] W-9000-model com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerThread - Retry worker: 9000-44f1cd64 in 1 seconds.
```

The worker dies and tries to restart, and the process repeats till I stop the container.

The model I am using is trained with pytorch 1.5. But since EI support is only supported till 1.3.1, I am using this container.

Things I have tried:

1. The same code with same model works outside the container with pytorch version 1.3.1. So, I don't think pytorch version compatibility is the issue.
2. Tried using `debug` and `notset` levels for logs. Didn't get any more info as to why model loading fails
3. Tried loading the original model instead of the traced one. Again this works in 1.5 but not in 1.3.1. Fails at the same point, while loading the BERT pretrained model.
4. Tried this setup on sagemaker notebook instance with gpu accelerator and sagemaker `PytorchModel's deploy()` function with `framework_version` as 1.3.1. Also tried it using the 1.3.1 container without `eia`. Has same behaviour everywhere.

Am I doing something wrong or missing something crucial from the documentation? Any help would be much appreciated.

**Logs for container with torch 1.3.1-eia **

```
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:14,333 [INFO ] main com.amazonaws.ml.mms.ModelServer - 
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | MMS Home: /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Current directory: /
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Temp directory: /home/model-server/tmp
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Number of GPUs: 0
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Number of CPUs: 8
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Max heap size: 6972 M
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Python executable: /opt/conda/bin/python
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Config file: /etc/sagemaker-mms.properties
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Inference address: http://0.0.0.0:8080
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Management address: http://0.0.0.0:8080
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Model Store: /.sagemaker/mms/models
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Initial Models: ALL
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Log dir: /logs
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Metrics dir: /logs
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Netty threads: 0
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Netty client threads: 0
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Default workers per model: 1
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Blacklist Regex: N/A
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Maximum Response Size: 6553500
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Maximum Request Size: 6553500
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Preload model: false
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Prefer direct buffer: false
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:14,391 [WARN ] W-9000-model com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - attachIOStreams() threadName=W-9000-model
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:14,481 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - model_service_worker started with args: --sock-type unix --sock-name /home/model-server/tmp/.mms.sock.9000 --handler sagemaker_pytorch_serving_container.handler_service --model-path /.sagemaker/mms/models/model --model-name model --preload-model false --tmp-dir /home/model-server/tmp
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:14,482 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Listening on port: /home/model-server/tmp/.mms.sock.9000
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:14,482 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - [PID] 51
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:14,482 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - MMS worker started.
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:14,483 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Python runtime: 3.6.6
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:14,483 [INFO ] main com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.ModelManager - Model model loaded.
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:14,487 [INFO ] main com.amazonaws.ml.mms.ModelServer - Initialize Inference server with: EpollServerSocketChannel.
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:14,496 [INFO ] W-9000-model com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerThread - Connecting to: /home/model-server/tmp/.mms.sock.9000
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:14,544 [INFO ] main com.amazonaws.ml.mms.ModelServer - Inference API bind to: http://0.0.0.0:8080
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:14,545 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Connection accepted: /home/model-server/tmp/.mms.sock.9000.
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | Model server started.
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:14,547 [WARN ] pool-2-thread-1 com.amazonaws.ml.mms.metrics.MetricCollector - worker pid is not available yet.
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:14,962 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - PyTorch version 1.3.1 available.
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,314 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Lock 140580224398952 acquired on /root/.cache/torch/transformers/26bc1ad6c0ac742e9b52263248f6d0f00068293b33709fae12320c0e35ccfbbb.542ce4285a40d23a559526243235df47c5f75c197f04f37d1a0c124c32c9a084.lock
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,315 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-uncased-vocab.txt not found in cache or force_download set to True, downloading to /root/.cache/torch/transformers/tmpcln39mxo
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,344 [WARN ] W-9000-model-stderr com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,349 [WARN ] W-9000-model-stderr com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Downloading:   0%|          | 0.00/232k [00:00<?, ?B/s]
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,349 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - storing https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-uncased-vocab.txt in cache at /root/.cache/torch/transformers/26bc1ad6c0ac742e9b52263248f6d0f00068293b33709fae12320c0e35ccfbbb.542ce4285a40d23a559526243235df47c5f75c197f04f37d1a0c124c32c9a084
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,349 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - creating metadata file for /root/.cache/torch/transformers/26bc1ad6c0ac742e9b52263248f6d0f00068293b33709fae12320c0e35ccfbbb.542ce4285a40d23a559526243235df47c5f75c197f04f37d1a0c124c32c9a084
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,349 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Lock 140580224398952 released on /root/.cache/torch/transformers/26bc1ad6c0ac742e9b52263248f6d0f00068293b33709fae12320c0e35ccfbbb.542ce4285a40d23a559526243235df47c5f75c197f04f37d1a0c124c32c9a084.lock
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,350 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - loading file https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-uncased-vocab.txt from cache at /root/.cache/torch/transformers/26bc1ad6c0ac742e9b52263248f6d0f00068293b33709fae12320c0e35ccfbbb.542ce4285a40d23a559526243235df47c5f75c197f04f37d1a0c124c32c9a084
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,378 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Created tokenizer
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,378 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Elastic Inference enabled: True
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,378 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - inside model fn
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,379 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - /.sagemaker/mms/models/model
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,379 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - /.sagemaker/mms/models/model/model.pt
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,379 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - ['model.pt', 'model.tar.gz', 'code', 'model_tn_best.pth', 'MAR-INF']
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,379 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Loading torch script
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,392 [INFO ] epollEventLoopGroup-4-1 com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerThread - 9000-44f1cd64 Worker disconnected. WORKER_STARTED
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,392 [WARN ] W-9000-model com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.BatchAggregator - Load model failed: model, error: Worker died.
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:15,393 [INFO ] W-9000-model com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerThread - Retry worker: 9000-44f1cd64 in 1 seconds.
algo-1-nvqf7_1  | 2020-11-30 07:17:16,065 [INFO ] W-9000-model ACCESS_LOG - /172.18.0.1:45110 "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 8
```

Comment: You model_fn seems to load to CPU, shouldn't it load to EIA?

Comment: As per the documentation, it has to be loaded to CPU. Only during prediction, in `torch.jit.optimized_execution` we have to pass in the target device as the accelerator. https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/using_pytorch.html#load-a-model